# Can I write on the same NFS share from several OS?

Tags: nfs

We have a NAS (maybe using BTRFS) that shares one NFS as RW.

We can mount this share as RW from several OS.

**Question**: will the filesystems get corrupted if several independent OS mounts the NFS share and write many files to it?

Answer (score 4):

No, NFS is designed to support this type of usage. In fact, not only is it designed to support multiple clients (any network filesystem would do this), it was specifically designed to support a wide variety of client operating systems (see the [original paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.473) for details).

The only risk of corruption is if multiple clients write to the same file without coordinating. Typically, this is avoided by using locking, *e.g.* using [`fcntl(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html).